# "Job for wg-quick@wg0.service failed because the control process exited with error code"

Tags: ubuntu, wireguard

I am trying to install wireguard on Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit, following one of the video tutorials.

Step `systemctl start wg-quick@wg0.service` finishes with

```
Job for wg-quick@wg0.service failed because the control process exited with error code. 
See "systemctl status wg-quick@wg0.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Running `systemctl status wg-quick@wg0.service` gives:

```
● wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2023-03-11 00:02:48 UTC; 7min ago
     Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
           man:wg(8)
           https://www.wireguard.com/
           https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
           https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
           https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
  Process: 18984 ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up wg0 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18984 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name systemd[1]: Starting WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name wg-quick[18984]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name wg-quick[18984]: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name wg-quick[18984]: Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported
Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name wg-quick[18984]: [#] ip link delete dev wg0
Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name wg-quick[18984]: Cannot find device "wg0"
Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name systemd[1]: wg-quick@wg0.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 11 00:02:48 my-vps.name systemd[1]: Failed to start WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

Running `journalctl -xe` shows:

```
Mar 10 23:46:27 my-vps.name wg-quick[18951]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
Mar 10 23:46:27 my-vps.name wg-quick[18951]: RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported
Mar 10 23:46:27 my-vps.name wg-quick[18951]: Unable to access interface: Protocol not supported
Mar 10 23:46:27 my-vps.name wg-quick[18951]: [#] ip link delete dev wg0
Mar 10 23:46:27 my-vps.name wg-quick[18951]: Cannot find device "wg0"
```

My `wg0.conf` looks like:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = myprivatekeyhere
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51830
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o venet0 -j MASQUERADE
```

`modprobe wireguard` says:

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wireguard not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0
```

`ls /lib/modules` returns:

```
4.15.0  4.15.0-206-generic
```

`uname -r` shows:

```
4.15.0
```

Rebooting did not help. Searching did not help.

Answer (score 0):

so, yeah, as the error says: you don't have the wireguard module for your kernel, hence cannot do wireguard.

You need to build and install the wireguard module (because your using a very old distro, the kernel is old, so there's no in-kernel wireguard, and you need to install it separately; if you have the universe repos enabled, install `wireguard-dkms`. Better, update to a more modern Ubuntu; there's been two long-term support releases since back then. Anything with a Linux kernel > 5.6 will probably have the wireguard module included; so, go for Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: I tried it with Ubuntu 22.04, getting the same error. The reason really was that I used VPS based on OpenVZ virtualization. It requires other approuch of installing. This article describes how to install it. https://d.sb/2019/07/wireguard-on-openvz-lxc But it also requres TUN being enabled.